# Fixing btrfs file extent holes

Tags: filesystems, btrfs, fsck

So, due to what I assume to be a loose ATX connector my system powered down unexpectedly. Which is bad. When I run btrfs check I find a mile long list of extent holes. Fortunately they are limited to the volume specificly meant to handle data that changes a lot (logs and cache), and the data I actually care about seems okay.

I ran a scrub and the effected volume seems to be okay, but I still have these holes. I don't really want to use btrfs check to fix them until I know for sure if that is wise.

So...what do I do and what can I expect? I'm pretty sure repairing is the way to go, but anytime data is involved I always like to be sure.

edit: One thing I should mention is that volume is functional as is. It has my OS on it as well as /boot.

edit2: Also, for what it's worth, I'm running kernel version 4.14.4-1-ARCH with btrfs-progs version 4.14-1.

Comment: You seems to already know the answer....multiple inconsistencies expected in non-important files.

Comment: No, I don't know, I suspect. I'm not system administrator. I have above average knowledge of stuff, and my Goggle-fu is pretty decent, but when Google can't help me I have to ask for help. When it comes to data, even data that isn't especially valuable, I don't take chances. That volume also has my OS on it. I could rsync my back up to a new volume, but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't much of an answer, but for those of you who might come accross this question because you yourself have a similar issue I figure I should mention the result.

It was impractical to leave things be, so I went ahead an fixed the problem with `btrfs check --repair` from my fall back installation of Arch. On subsequent checks, no errors were found, nor when I followed up with a scrub were there any errors. I then went ahead a compared the volume against backups, but there was so much to go through I can't decide if there is anything to worry about. I got through about 25% of it and didn't find anything that concerned me, and my system is working fine. Consider it has the OS, cache/config, and other such things that make the system run properly, everything is most likely okay.